# What is the fastest way to change a clustered index on a 64GB table?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2019

We have a table (64 GB in size, 256795926 rows) which has a very bad PK (clustered) index. Currently it's a `varchar(99)` column (average size 50 characters).

There is already a `bigint identity` column, so we would like to convert the PK to this column.

However altering a PK is not possible, so a drop / recreate seems the only solution. But this table is constantly updated, so downtime must be a minimum. We have SQL Server 2019 Enterprise, but online dropping / recreating would be a very long time I guess, and the logfile will be also huge.

I am thinking of recreating a new table with the correct structure, transfer the latest ID to this new table (so my identities are ok) and transfer the data to this new table. To my opinion this will give the least downtime, but does somebody have a better idea?

Comment: Perhaps [partition switching](https://www.littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/)

Comment: @Stu - I think that's a no go as the OP wants to change the indexes and partition switching requires that the indexes be the same on the source/target. Unless you're thinking of something a little more... exotic?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't take the downtime, then an copy to a new table followed by a final incremental copy/rename/drop in a transaction is the only way to go.

Comment: I'll try to create a test environment to develop a solution. I'll post the scripts when I am satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 alternatives:

**Enterprise Edition:** If you are on SQL Server Enterprise Edition you can use `WITH (ONLINE=ON)`:

```
DROP INDEX [Old_Index] ON dbo.Table;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_Table ON dbo.Table(ID) WITH (ONLINE=ON);
GO
```

I haven't tested but you could also use `WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW, ONLINE = ON);` it might be faster. I don't knwo. Sorry, I don't have time test it right now for you :(

**Standard Edition:** You have to schedule a maintenance window

Comment: The problem I have is the downtime (or actually the time the table is locked), this solution won't fix that. Dropping a clustered index from a 64GB table with a constant load of insert/update/delete is not an option. Creating the index again with online=on will fix the locking issue a little, but this will take hours and probably a very large logfile

Comment: Are you on Enterprise Edition @WilfredvanDijk ?

Comment: yes, read my initial question

Comment: cool, so that is the only option for you. The solution is to use `with online=on`. Tha't it.